# Server startup error

Tags: c#

Server start up error when trying to add a purger timer ( game feature) seems that the server is not allowed access?

PurgeTimer:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Plus.HabboHotel.GameClients;
using Plus.HabboHotel.Rooms;

namespace Plus.HabboHotel.Minigames.Purge
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This will do a countdown before the match starts
    /// </summary>
    public class PurgeTimer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Timer for our operation
        /// </summary>
        private Timer Timer;

        public bool On = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public PurgeTimer()
        {
            // Method to call when completed
            TimerCallback TimerCallback = Ticked;

            // Create a new instance of timer
            Timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 30000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method is call when timer is finished
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info">The information</param>
        public void Ticked(object info)
        {
            try
            {

                if (PurgeManager.Running)
                {
                    foreach (GameClient client in PlusEnvironment.GetGame().GetClientManager()._clients.Values)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (client == null)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            client.SendWhisper("[Automatic Event Alert]: The hotel is currently under Purge Mode. All crime is legal.");

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }
                    }

                    Timer.Change(30000, Timeout.Infinite);
                }
                else
                {

                    return;
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

PurgeManager:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Plus.HabboHotel.Minigames.Purge;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Plus.HabboHotel.Minigames.Purge
{
    public class PurgeManager
    {
        public static PurgeTimer MainTimer;
        public static bool Running;
    }
}
```

Error:
http://prntscr.com/9ss0qb  I don't get while it's not accessible!

Comment: Post the error message here, yea.

Comment: Error 1 Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal C:\Users\BAB\Desktop\Boon Emu\HabboHotel\Minigames\Purge\PurgeManager.cs 10 18 Plus Emulator

Error 2 'Plus.HabboHotel.GameClients.GameClientManager._clients' is inaccessible due to its protection level C:\Users\BAB\Desktop\Boon Emu\HabboHotel\Minigames\Purge\PurgeTimer.cs 45 96 Plus Emulator

Comment: post the GameClientManager

Comment: too long http://pastebin.com/1ECVTBZt @DevEstacion

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please post the error directly into the question, not as a linked image.

The error `Plus.HabboHotel.GameClients.GameClientManager._clients is inaccessible due to its protection level` seems pretty clear.  From the naming convention used I'd take a guess that the `_clients` collection is private.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem.

From your `GameClientManager` class, you're trying to access a private field.

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<int, GameClient> _clients;
```

For more details regarding your problem, review this. [What are Access Modifiers in C#?](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/what-are-access-modifiers-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Thanks, That table helps!

Error 1 Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal C:\Users\BAB\Desktop\Boon Emu\HabboHotel\Minigames\Purge\PurgeManager.cs 10 18 Plus Emulator

This comes up now!

Comment: is the code of PurgeManager complete? post the whole class

Comment: are these classes in a single file?

Comment: Everything related to purge is in these two files

Comment: place the two files here. complete, so we can help you further.